# preg_match error

Tags: preg-match

I have found this function on the web, but when I paste it into dreamweaver or netbeans, they flag up a line error:

```
function valid_date($date){
        $search = '^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/';
        if(preg_match($search, $date)){ //**** error on this line ****
           echo 'go';
        }else{
           echo 'no go';
        }
}
```

When I load it in the browser, it comes up with an unexpected T_STRING error.

Does anyone have any ideas why?

UPDATED CODE:

```
function valid_date($date){
    $search = '/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/';
    if(preg_match($search, $date)){
            echo 'go';
    }else{
            echo 'no go';
    }
}
```

screenshot - http://www.nickstestsite.co.uk/preg_match.png"

Comment: After adding the missing `/` at the start of your regex (which you said you already had but isn't in the question for some reason), your code runs without error on my machine. You may need to provide more detail or context.

Comment: Thanks for your help and replies; when I type the function into dreamweaver, I just get a syntax error flag on the "if(preg_match" line. Netbeans says the same, syntax error on that line. Doesn't seem to be about the regex - just the preg_match function. When uploaded, I get this message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line (same line as the error messages). Will paste my code as it stands below...

Comment: Again, the updated code your post, copied and pasted into a file on my system, works correctly. The PHP error "unexpected T_STRING" usually means that you're missing a quote or braces somewhere *else* in your code prior to the line that's actually indicated. The real source of the error may be many lines of code away.

Comment: That's totally weird! Even when I paste it into a seperate file just on it's own, I still get the same error messages

Comment: I have just posted a screenshot of dreamweaver. I get the same t-string error in the browser when I upload it. Doing my head in now!!

Answer (score 1):

You need a leading `/` in your `$search` variable. In PHP, the `/`'s denote the beginning and the end of a regular expression.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, I do actually have a / at the start... not sure why it didn't copy! The error message however shows up on the if(preg_match line - like I've missed some syntax or something??